# How can I redirect requests to specific files to pages hosted by other servers?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

When requesting for a local file, I would like to see a 301 redirection should lead to a page on a different server (an URL is provided). This can be usually done by using a simple `Redirect` directive, but this would cause some maintenance headache in my case: It does not support redirecting files (given their names) under specific directories that may frequently changes. For me, the best situation would be to use something similar to symbolic links with additional support for "linking" to URLs outside the host. In addition, with `Options +Indexes`, this "redirection" file can also be listed.

Comment: "This can be usually done by using a simple Redirect directive, but this would cause some maintenance headache in my case: It does not support redirecting files (given their names) under specific directories that may frequently changes." - Can you please give an example of the type of redirect you are referring to. The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, so it can be used to target whole/specific directories if you need it to.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Makes Apache redirect only if the target file doesn't exist on this server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ http://your-file-storage.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This configuration makes all requests to `http://your-app.com/assets/*` be redirected to `http://your-file-storage.com/*`. For example, the URL `http://your-app.com/assets/foo/bar.txt` will be redirected to `http://your-file-storage.com/foo/bar.txt`.

The `^assets/(.*)$` string is a regular expression which tests URLs. If a URL fits the regular expression, it is redirected.

The `http://your-file-storage.com/$1` string is the redirect target. The `$1` is replaced with the regular expression parentheses content.

If you need many redirect rules, add many `RewriteRule` directives to the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^assets1/(.*)$ http://your-file-storage1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^assets2/(.*)$ http://your-file-storage2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively you can add a `RedirectMatch` directive to the virtual host configuration in the Apache configuration file:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/assets/(.*)$ http://your-file-storage.com/$1
```

It works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

This may do the trick: `RedirectMatch 301 .*/<filename> <redirect target>`.

The wildcard `.*` tells Apache to match anything up to the actual file name, so the frequently-changing directories won't be a problem.

If you need to match specific directory names, and you have a finite list of them, you can list all of them in a single rule: `RedirectMatch 301 .*/(dir1|dir2|dir3|...)/<filename <redirect target>`.